# kusto query with dynamic object value without key

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I have a lot of data looking like

```
{"tuesday":"<30, 60>"}  
{"friday":"<0, 5>"} 
{"saturday":"<5, 10>"}  
{"friday":"<0, 5>"} 
{"saturday":"<5, 10>"}  
{"sunday":"0"}  
{"monday":"<0, 5>"}
```

All i want is the value regardless of the key.

My query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "eventName"
| extend d = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.['Properties']))
| project d
| take 7
```

d is a dynamic object and I can do d.monday for the value, but I'd like to get the value without the key. Is this possible with Kusto?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the case of a single-property as you've demonstrated above, using the `parse` operator could work:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    ,dynamic({"tuesday":"<30, 60>"})
    ,dynamic({"friday":"<0, 5>"})
    ,dynamic({"saturday":"<5, 10>"})
    ,dynamic({"friday":"<0, 5>"})
    ,dynamic({"saturday":"<5, 10>"})
    ,dynamic({"sunday":"0"})
    ,dynamic({"monday":"<0, 5>"})
]
| parse d with * ':"'  value '"' *
| project value
```

**Notes:**

- In case your values are not necessarily encapsulated in double quotes (e.g. are numerics), then you should be able to specify `kind=regex` for the `parse` operator, and use a conditional expression for the existence of the double quotes.
- In case you have potentially more than 1 property per property bag, using `extract_all()` is an option.

**Relevant Docs:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parseoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/extractallfunction

Comment: Excellent, the parse operator missed me.. Thanks so much for the included docs!